# Freenove Camera not able to interface with Raspberry pi 4 + Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, picamera, libcamera, robotics

I am trying to work on a project where I want to use ROS. However, I found that for using ROS Noetic, I will need to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my Raspberry pi 4. Now, I bought a camera module (Freenove FK0056B) recently. So, when I try to run a program either on python or command line using 'fswebcam', I am not able to capture an image or video through the camera even though the Pi is detecting the device at '/dev/video0'.

When I use the command: `fswebcam test1.jpg`, I get the following errors:

```
Error starting stream
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_DQBUF: Invalid argument
No Frames captured.
```

Also, when I try to run the Python script using OpenCV library. I am not able to get any image as the Frame value is `NONE`.

Can you please assist with this please?